# Why level order traversal is not considered as types of traversal?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, traversal

Only 3 types of traversal are considered .They are Inorder , postorder ,preorder traversal .Why not Level order considered as a type ?

Answer (score 0):

> Only 3 types of traversal are considered

Ignoring that a source is lacking for this statement, there are certainly more types that are considered in tree traversal algorithms.

> They are Inorder , postorder ,preorder traversal

These are traversals that belong to one particular family of traversals: the depth-first family.

> Why not Level order considered as a type?

It is certainly is considered. It is more commonly known as [breadth first traversal](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/breadth-first/). The referenced article explains:

> A preorder [...] type of traversal is called a depth-first traversal.
>
> [...] inorder and postorder traversals, like a preorder traversal, also try to go deeper first...
>
> #### 3. Breadth-first traversal:
>
> Depth-first is not the only way to go through the elements of a tree. Another way is to go through them level-by-level.
>
> [...] This level-by-level traversal is called a breadth-first traversal because we explore the breadth, i.e., full width of the tree at a given level, before going deeper.

Breadth-first traversals are important in many algorithms, notably shortest-path finding algorithms.

Like with depth-first traversals, there are also variants in the breadth-first family. For instance [zigzag](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zigzag-tree-traversal/).

When the tree has weighted edges, then there are also the [best-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) searches to be considered.